# How to stop Canvas from Resizing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF canvas were I can drag and drop a control. So whenever I resize the control and when the control's right edge reaches the right edge of the canvas, the canvas's width starts to increase.

I had set the Height,MaxHeight and MinHeight to 1122 and MaxWidth,MinWidth and Width to 794.

But still the size changes.

Is there any other property to set?

Comment: Are you sure you're not changing the canvas sizing indirectly when you resize the child control?

Comment: Could you set a maxWidth on the child control, to prevent it reaching the edge of the canvas?

Comment: How do you observe or measure the Canvas size?

Comment: @DeanChalk Thanks. The size was changing indirectly due to the implementation of MeasureOverride override method in the class which had the code for actually increasing the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size was changing indirectly due to the implementation of MeasureOverride override method in the class which had the code for actually increasing the size.